# VGA 1gb not running old games with good graphics?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card

We have an Intel DG41WV motherboard with integrated graphics with 1024 MB ram with the latest driver installed, the driver seems to work perfectly although when we want to play games, there's something weird happening the picture is blue like we're running new games on low VGA RAM, even the FIFA 2008 is not working with good graphics, and this game is working on other computers with lower VGA RAM and perfectly.

so what could be the problem?

computer specifications:

```
Processor: Intel Dual Core  
Ram: 2 GB  
VGA: 1 GB  
OS: Windows XP Pro
```

Comment: i have a dg41ty board and it also have some problem with some games. but it is normal with integrated graphics. so i upgrade to dedicated graphics card recently.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the memory size of your graphics adapter is not that important.
There are other values that can be crucial for running graphic applications (PC games)
such as the Core Clock, Memory Interface (and type [DDR2/GDDR5 etc.]) and yes - **also** the Memory Size.

From what I understand - you got built-in graphics card.

I would recommend these solutions:

- Lower the video settings of your games (lower the general quality)
- If your'e having visual [artifacts](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html) and distortions - try to check the temperature of your graphics card (Though it's more relevant for external cards)
- Upgrade your PC with some brand new (and **external**) graphics card.

All of the "normal" external cards these days will give you better performance than the built-in ones (normal = mid-end cards and forward)

Note that built in cards designated to "office" usage.
You can try to run games with these cards, though you'll have to compromise performance.